# PyCharm exclude file from inspections

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Is there any opportunity to exclude `.css` file which i generate from `.scss` with `File Watcher` from declaration search (`Ctrl + click` or `Command + click` in mac os)?

There is a [JetBrains article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/excluding-files-from-project.html), but for some reason i can't declare my `.css` file as plain text.

Comment: Making as Plain Text is the most obvious way. Especially if you have `.css` next to the source `.scss` file (same folder). The other possible solution -- keep `.css` files in a separate folder .. so then you may exclude whole folder. **P.S.** Mark as Plain Text may not work if file is already part of some Library or Excluded folder (here is a ticket for PHP/PhpStorm .. but maybe similar kind of logic works in PyCharm as well: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22649)

Comment: @LazyOne, thank you.